How to reserve a CPU core for a script in a shared server without root privileges?
Suppose that I have a script executable on a Linux remote server shared by other employees. (it could be a bash .sh script, a julia .jl script, for example). I believe tasks of all users are affected FIFO. How can I assure that there is exactly a fixed number (for instance 4 or 1) of core(s) totally available for my numerical experiments?
I have to launch numerical experiments on such a remote server and often, the load capacity of the server exceeds 31 cores out of 32 and I don't have root privileges on this server.
Note that the fixed number of cores that are allocated to my program could be only 1 CPU core if it is not possible to set it to a higher value.

You should be able to use taskset to acomplish your task.

@Ramhound, thanks for your comment. If I use taskset to give an affinity of a CPU to a task, I think it won't prevent other users to use this CPU partially during my task, right?

You setting the process affinity of a bash script won't prevent any other user also logged in. I am not aware of a method reserve cores for a specific process, especially, if it's not actually running. Why are you not using a VM allowing you to pin cores for that VM within the host operating system?

@Ramhound, as my aim is not to perform my task as fast as possible but to perform it as fast as possible with a single CPU (or any fixed number) always available (a little like on a personal computer), I believe setting an affinity thanks to taskset is not the answer of my question unfortunately... Do you have any other ideas? Thank you a lot :)

@Ramhound, I would greatly love to set a VM within the host operating system. Can I do it without root privileges?

You might need root privilege.  I just know you can pin specific cores for the use by a VM, this would reserve those cores, while the VM was running. This would effectively pin those cores for the script's use.

@Ramhound, as I can't set a VM without root privileges, I think pin specific cores to a VM is not a solution too, do you have any other ideas? ^^ Maybe my answer just does not have a solution (and thus, the problem disappears!)
